# Monit is reporting low memory use

Tags: memory, memory-usage, monit

Monit is reporting very low memory use that is not consistent with actual use.

If I look at Monit, under System I see "5.7% [918.0 MB]" though the real scenario is very different;

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         15947      14755       1191       1495        889      11508
-/+ buffers/cache:       2357      13590
Swap:         8191        113       8078
```

Memory use is actually around 90% and 14.7GB.

It reports similar low use for PHP-FPM at "5.0% [799.1 MB]".

Not sure what I can do to make it report the correct use?

Note that my db server reports correctly "83.4% [13.0 GB]".

**EDIT**

Just noticed this in release notes;

"Fixed: On 32-bit platforms with more then 4GB of RAM, Monit reported incorrect system and swap memory values (regression in Monit 5.16)."

Going to upgrade and see if it fixes it.

**EDIT 2**

Have upgraded to monit 5.17.1 and the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

memory use isn't 14Gb. That adds in filesystem cache memory. See the following website for more info. Short info is Linux will use all memory on the system to make commonly used files quickly accessible. It will release that memory when needed by processes. Take a look at the line for `-/+ buffers/cache` for your true free memory

http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Monit is reporting your memory ok for php

Comment: Argh, yes, I've read about this before. That makes sense. Thanks very much.